# Problem with puppeteer web scrape Problem

Tags: javascript, web, puppeteer, scrape

I have the need to scrape a list of 113 URLs to collect the **Title**, **ImageURL** and **Content** from those URLs and put them into a JSON / Text file to import later.

But I can't seem to get it to work properly. I have now gotten the loop to work, as go to the URLs but the return results are undefined, not sure why the returned data isn't coming through.

Could I get some help on this?

**EDIT**

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

let scrape = async (i, url) => {
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false // Show Browser
});

// Load a new page
const page = await browser.newPage();

// Set viewport size
await page.setViewport({ width: 1366, height: 768, deviceScaleFactor: 1 });

// Go to URL
await page.goto(`${url}`, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });

// Run the scrape over the page
const results = await page.evaluate(() => {
    // H2 Heading
    let title = document.querySelector('div.wsite-section-elements > h2.wsite-content-title').innerText;
    // Image
    let imageURL = document.querySelector('div.wsite-section-elements > div > div > a> img').getAttribute('src');
    // Paragraph
    let txtContent = document.querySelector('div.wsite-section-elements > div.paragraph').innerText;

});

//Close Browser
await browser.close();

// Return scrape results
return results;
};

(async () => {
// Pages to scrape
let pageURLs = ['https://www.bibleed.com/the-divine-origin-of-the-bible.html','https://www.bibleed.com/the-bible-our-guide.html'];

for(let i = 0; i < pageURLs.length; i++)
{
    await scrape(i, pageURLs[i]).then((value) => {
        console.log(i, ': ', value);
    });
}

// Write to file
//const fs = require('fs');
//fs.writeFileSync('webScrape3.txt', JSON.stringify(result), err => err ? console.log(err): null);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You create a `pamphletData` variable inside a for-loop, which is not accessible outside of it. So when you do `JSON.stringify(pamphletData)`, you actually do `JSON.stringify(undefined)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not puppeteer issue. You are not returning anything from dom.

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

let scrape = async (i, url) => {
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false // Show Browser
});

// Load a new page
const page = await browser.newPage();

// Set viewport size
await page.setViewport({ width: 1366, height: 768, deviceScaleFactor: 1 });

// Go to URL
await page.goto(`${url}`, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });

// Run the scrape over the page
const results = await page.evaluate(() => {
    // H2 Heading
    let title = document.querySelector('div.wsite-section-elements > h2.wsite-content-title').innerText;
    // Image
    let imageURL = document.querySelector('div.wsite-section-elements > div > div > a> img').getAttribute('src');
    // Paragraph
    let txtContent = document.querySelector('div.wsite-section-elements > div.paragraph').innerText;

    return { title, imageURLm txtContent };

});

//Close Browser
await browser.close();

// Return scrape results
return results;
};

(async () => {
// Pages to scrape
let pageURLs = ['https://www.bibleed.com/the-divine-origin-of-the-bible.html','https://www.bibleed.com/the-bible-our-guide.html'];

for(let i = 0; i < pageURLs.length; i++)
{
    await scrape(i, pageURLs[i]).then((value) => {
        console.log(i, ': ', value);
    });
}

// Write to file
//const fs = require('fs');
//fs.writeFileSync('webScrape3.txt', JSON.stringify(result), err => err ? console.log(err): null);
})();
```